# Google chart, I want to write some text at the right of each point in graph

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Google chart, I want to write some text at the right side of some points in the graph. How can I do that?

The chart has three different series Low, High, Multiple, A dashed line should be there which starts from "Low" value to "Multiple" value. X axis should have Ticks like PC#1, PC#2, PC#3 etc. Also each point should have its value at the right of it within the graph not as tool-tip. The graph should have three legends as we have three series "Low", "High", "Multiple".

[Please click on this image link to understand my requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3ufD.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can place *text* next to a point on a chart using *annotations*

*annotations* are added using a data column, directly following the series column it should represent

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawVisualization();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawVisualization, false);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
  data.addRow([{v: 2, f: ''}, 0.8, '0.8x']);
  data.addRow([{v: 2, f: ''}, 7.4, '7.4x']);
  data.addRow([{v: 2, f: ''}, 12.2, '12.2x']);

  var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(container);

  chart.draw(data, {
    hAxis: {
      ticks: [
        {v: 0, f: ''},
        {v: 1, f: ''},
        {v: 2, f: ''},
        {v: 3, f: ''},
        {v: 4, f: ''}
      ]
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="visualization"></div>
```

---

by default, *annotations* are placed above the point, as seen in the above snippet

and there are no standard options available to move the annotation left or right

only up or down using --> `annotations.stem.length`

in order to set the text to the *right* of the point,
the text needs to be moved manually,
when the `'ready'` event fires on the chart

see following working snippet...

the *annotations* will be added as `text` elements to the svg

when the ready event fires, the annotation `text` elements are found,
and the `'x'` attribute is changed, to move the `text` to the *right*

`annotations.stem.length` is used to bring the text down to the same height as the point

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawVisualization();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawVisualization, false);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
  data.addRow([{v: 2, f: ''}, 0.8, '0.8x']);
  data.addRow([{v: 2, f: ''}, 7.4, '7.4x']);
  data.addRow([{v: 2, f: ''}, 12.2, '12.2x']);

  var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('text'), function (text, index) {
      if (text.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') {
        text.setAttribute('x', parseFloat(text.getAttribute('x')) + 20);
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, {
    annotations: {
      stem: {
        length: -5
      }
    },
    hAxis: {
      ticks: [
        {v: 0, f: ''},
        {v: 1, f: ''},
        {v: 2, f: ''},
        {v: 3, f: ''},
        {v: 4, f: ''}
      ]
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="visualization"></div>
```

---

*however*, you will notice in the above snippet,
when you hover over one of the points,
the chart will set the text back to the original `'x'` position

this can be prevented by *turning off* interactivity using the following option...
`enableInteractivity: false`

but if you would like to keep interactivity,
you'll need to reset the `'x'` position anytime an event occurs

this can be accomplished by using a `MutationObserver`

see following working snippet...

when the `'ready'` event fires, the new `'x'` position is calculated for each `text` element

then the `MutationObserver` is used to reset the position,
anytime interactivity occurs...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawVisualization();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawVisualization, false);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
  data.addRow([{v: 2, f: ''}, 0.8, '0.8x']);
  data.addRow([{v: 2, f: ''}, 7.4, '7.4x']);
  data.addRow([{v: 2, f: ''}, 12.2, '12.2x']);

  var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(container);

  var annotations = {};
  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('text'), function (text, index) {
      if (text.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') {
        annotations[index] = parseFloat(text.getAttribute('x')) + 20;
      }
    });

    var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('text'), function (text, index) {
        if (text.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') {
          text.setAttribute('x', annotations[index]);
        }
      });
    });
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, {
    annotations: {
      stem: {
        length: -5
      }
    },
    hAxis: {
      ticks: [
        {v: 0, f: ''},
        {v: 1, f: ''},
        {v: 2, f: ''},
        {v: 3, f: ''},
        {v: 4, f: ''}
      ]
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="visualization"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought in the same way to do but didn't have this much of understanding. One more thing in the graph image which I attached top most point is having triangle and is connect with lowest point with a dashed line.

Comment: How can I do that ? Do I need to create a separate chart for the topmost point, within the same chart as we do in combochart. I also tried to create annotations for lowest point and putting stem length upto the highest point. But how can I set stem length dynamically for all the lowest points in the graph. Also you have already set one annotation for points in your example so can we set two annotations for one point where one annotation will be in vertical direction with a line and another annotation will be right side of the point as you explained. Please help in this regard.

Comment: Please see this fiddle to understand what I tried and please help me to create the same type of graph which I attached in image: https://jsfiddle.net/sainirohit77/34e32evn/

Comment: you can assign [`pointShape`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/points) to get triangle and use [`'certainty'` column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available) to get dash -- will you please accept the answer? just start another question for the others if you get stuck

Comment: I have accepted the answer but its not increasing the up-vote count as i have joined recently.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I need one more help. Your solution has all the points in one column "y", on mouse over shows "y, 0.8" or "y, 7.4" etc. My need is that all the three points are three different columns eg. "low", "high", "multiple". And there will be many rows of such columns. My data set would be like this:  var array = [
        ['AC#1', 100, 120, 150],
        ['AC#2', 120, 150, 180],
        ['AC#3', 130, 160, 190],
        ['AC#4', 90, 120, 200],
      ];    Also the x Axis ticks AC#1, AC#2 etc. should be displayed. Please help in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have updated my question and also provided a link for the image of graph which I am looking for. I appreciate your continuous help. Please have a look on the question and image and provide me help. I feel my graph is little strange where I have three different columns (Series) and also I have to draw a dashed line between column "Low" and "High", whereas in chart we draw the line between the points of same series/column. I am not able to understand how to achieve this. Please help , I am very hopeful by seeing your earlier reply, you really have sound knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
I am able to draw the chart as per my requirement. Please see below fiddle
for your reference:
[Fiddlle link][1]
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/sainirohit77/5xb68cfw/

The only problem which I can see would arise when the data points are very 
close to each other than the annotation text eg. 2.0x, 7.0x will overlap each 
other.
```